# The size/length of a QScrollBar

Tags: qt, user-interface, scrollbar, qwt

I'm working on a GUI with a Qwt plot and came across a seemingly banal problem - namely I can't resize a QScrollBar the way I would like to.
This is how the plot looks like:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6534o0&s=5#.UpXAwoZhauY

As you can see the vertical and horizontal scroll are bigger/longer than the size of plot canvas and I would like to make them smaller.
I tried scroll->setContentsMargin, I tried styling with margin or height/ width, tried using sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred, stretch=3) or overriding the sizeHint virtual function:

> QSize CScroll::sizeHint() const 
>   {
>
> > QSize s=QScrollBar::sizeHint();
> >     const QSize size(s.width()*0.5, s.height());
> >     return size;
> >     }

but as you can see in the screenshot - the size hint affects only the "thickness" of the scroll - so the vertical scroll is affected and the the horizontal one, not.

I also tried changing the grid layout so that it had one more column/row and empty cells to force the scrollbars to move, but that resulted in scrolls taking half of the space I wanted them too (and I'm no expert when it comes to using layouts).

PS. I am using custom scrollbars because using QScrollArea with a QwtPlot doesn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using layouts, you can simple add space item before and after scrollbar

Comment: Do you mean spacer? And if yes, how would I go about it to e.g make only horizontal scrollbar move (without moving the plot itself)?

My layout looks like this thus far:
--->>>plotLayout->addWidget(plot,0,0,1,1);
    plotLayout->addWidget(hScroll, 1, 0);
    plotLayout->addWidget(vScroll, 0,1, 2,1);
    plotLayout->addWidget(panel, 0,2,2,1);---<<< (sorry about the bad formating, don't know yet how it works)

Comment: QHBoxlayout* hl=new QHBoxLayout; hl->addSpasing(10); hl->addWidget(hScroll); hl->addSpasing(10); plotLayout->addLayout(hl, 1, 0);